# How to convince Scala.js to use Javascript defined method equals for comparison?

Tags: scala, scala.js, comparison-operators

*Background: the real projects uses [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) with a [facade](https://github.com/antonkulaga/threejs-facade). Both Three.js and the facade define the `equals` method for many types, including `Vector3`. This is a small sample demonstrating the `equals` functionality.*

I have a Javascript type which defines an `equals` method:

**MyType.js:**

```
function MyType(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

MyType.prototype.constructor = MyType;
MyType.prototype.equals = function(that) {
    return (this.x === that.x) && (this.y === that.y);
};

MyType.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "MyType(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
};
```

**MyType.scala** facade:

```scala
@js.native
@JSGlobal("MyType")
class MyType(var x: Double, var y: Double) extends js.Any {
  def equals(that: MyType): Boolean = js.native

  override def toString: String = js.native
}
```

The trouble is Scala.js seems to provide its own `equals` implementation which hides the one provided by the Javascript class for the purpose of comparisons.

In my test suite I have following code:

```scala
class MyTypeTest extends FunSuite {
  test("Basic test") {
    val my0 = new MyType(0, 0)
    val my1 = new MyType(0, 0)
    val e1 = my0 equals my1
    val e3 = my0 == my1
    val e4 = my0 === my1
    assert(e1, "equals")
    assert(e3, "==")
    assert(e4, "===")
  }
}
```

While the `e1` line calls the `MyType.equals`, `e3` and `e4` do not. I did not find any way how could I convince it to do so. I have tried changing the signature to `def equals(that: js.Any): Boolean` or even `override def equals(that: Any): Boolean`, still no luck.

The best I could do was pimping `====` operator and use that:

```scala
object MyType {
  implicit class PimpEquals(val myType: MyType) {
    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = {
      that match {
        case myTypeThat: MyType =>
          myType.equals(myTypeThat) // calls MyType.equals
        case _ =>
          myType.equals(that) // calls java.lang.Object.equals
      }
    }

    def ====(that: Any): Boolean = {
      equals(that)
    }
  }
}
```

(The pimped `equals` is not considered for normal `==`, which is no surprise given how the language is defined). Still the trouble with `====` is someone can use `==` operator by mistake and is given no warning.

Is there any way to convince Scala.js to use the `equals` implementation provided by the JavaScript class? If not, is there any way how to make it issue an error or warning (compile time preferably) when `==` is used on the `MyType`?

Note: complete ready-to-use project is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/jsequals).

Comment: time passed and we now have Scala3. I asked a similar question on the scala community space https://users.scala-lang.org/t/equals-on-scalajs-facade/7832

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial answer. I can use `@JSName` to overload `==` operator. It cannot be overridden, as it is final, but it can be overloaded:

```
@js.native
class MyType(var x: Double, var y: Double) extends js.Any {
  def equals(that: MyType): Boolean = js.native

  @JSName("equals")
  def ==(that: MyType): Boolean = js.native

  @JSName("equalsNot")
  def !=(that: MyType): Boolean = js.native

  override def toString: String = js.native
}
```

Note I am importing `equalsNot` as `!=`. Such function does not exist, but I want to be given error when someone attempts to use `!=`. Without overloading it would work silently, but with a different semantic than `==`.

I would prefer overriding `equals` somehow so that natural Scala implementations of `==` and `!=` are used, but I did not find a way so far. Perhaps someone else is able to come with some smarter solution?

Comment: I tried this answer. It compiles. But as I am using opaque types it does not work for me. 
Perhaps someone will find a better answer here https://users.scala-lang.org/t/equals-on-scalajs-facade/7832